# Should I read magazines directly after finding them?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there an advantage in keeping magazines like "Grognak the Barbarian" for later use? Or can I just get the +1 bonus now without any downside?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you pick up one of these items (whether that be an Astoundingly Awesome, a Tumblers Today or issue of Unstoppable, etc) it does the "legendary pickup" screen where you get an overview of the item as you pick it up. This is sufficient enough to activate the bonus that you get from that item and this bonus will be listed on the Perks page on your Pip Boy (under STAT > PERKS). You need no further interaction with these items once you've got the perk.

If you pick up multiple magazines in a single pick up, the "legendary pickup" screen will only show for the first one you picked up but all of them will be classed as read.

Comment: Do be sure to display them nicely in a magazine rack in your settlement afterwards ;) http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=557293295

Answer (score 17):

The magazines give a permanent bonus in Fallout 4 compared to the temporary bonuses they gave in New Vegas.  I would suggest picking them up whenever you find them.

When you select the magazine in your inventory, you get an option called "Read". You do not have to do this to gain the effect, it just shows you a close-up of the cover and stays in your inventory.

For the purposes of getting the perk, the magazine is "read" when you pick it up.

Source: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perk_magazines

Quote from source

> Magazines grant the player additional perks when read, or unlock certain benefits. These perks can have multiple ranks, with the rank increasing each time the player reads a copy of the magazine. The magazine may be sold or dropped after being read, and the perk or benefit will be retained.

Comment: "Picking them up" or "reading them directly"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes it does, you only need to pickup the magazines to get their effect.  If you try to read it, you get to inspect the cover, but it stays in your inventory.  I'll add in there you don't have to read it to gain the bonus, but try it for yourself.

Comment: What? this answer is pretty vague. "you do not have to read it to get the effect" but the quote says you DO need to read it.

The quote and the actual answer do not match.

Comment: Quick nit-pick: the bonuses conferred by magazines in Fallout 3 WERE permanent.  They were only temporary in New Vegas.

Comment: @LJ2 I forgot about that, since it has been a while.  I fixed that, thx.

Comment: @ids it isn't vague, and if you read the answer you would see it says it's considered read when picked up.  The source doesn't explain that, but it is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your collected magazines by transferring them to a magazine stand or rack that you have built in a settlement.

This is a nice little feature and a good reason to keep a magazine after you have read it.

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question, though. Perhaps this would be better as a comment?

Comment: My answer covers the OP's question clearly, they asked if there was a "advantage in keeping magazines" keeping them for display purposes, a feature that is not widely known. I wanted to make a comment but don't have the Rep required unfortunately.